# Enable jetty request logging/stats in Apache karaf container

Tags: java, jetty, apache-karaf, karaf, camel-http

Can anyone please tell us how to enable jetty logging to analyze the requests & other details(stats[parallel request/no of requests]) in Apache KARAF container.

Jetty.xml

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
            <Set name="KeyStore">restclient-path</Set>
            <Set name="KeyStorePassword">password</Set>
            <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">password</Set>
            <Set name="TrustStore">truststorepath</Set>
            <Set name="TrustStorePassword">password</Set>
            <Set name="needClientAuth">true</Set>
            <Set name="wantClientAuth">true</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
            <Set name="host">hostname</Set>
            <Set name="port">12345</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

I found the **statsOn** feature on the below blog but couldn't find the documentation for the attribute

[karaf documentation link](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/webcontainer)

Any reference would be helpful to enable logging.

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: No. We have written a filter to filter those requests through java. But that is not the expected one.